# Azure AD allow anonymous

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

Is it possible to use the `AllowAnonymous` attribute with Windows Azure AD?

I need a part of my web api to be anonymous, but not the actual website.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure AD does not need to support anonymous auth for you to be able to use the AllowAnonymous attribute in your WebAPI.

I believe what you desire is unauthenticated access to some controllers of the WebAPI. It is possible. See this .Net sample: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebAPI-ManuallyValidateJwt-DotNet/blob/master/TodoListService-ManualJwt/Global.asax.cs. It validates the token and sets the Thread.CurrentPrincipal if the token is valid and returns an error if it can't find a token.

For your WebAPI

- you wont return an error here - but instead not set the Thread.CurrentPrincipal when no token is present.
- then you will decorate your controllers with Authorize and AllowAnonymous attributes to disallow or allow anonymous access.

Comment: Thank you :) I gonna try that later :)

Comment: Look at my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25057396/1126393 but I think I gonna accept your answer :)

Comment: This code doesn't work, if I call the api it just redirects to the loginpage.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I could solve it by choosing in the Identity and Access windows that the auth should go in a controller. Then I added this code:

`CustomAuthorize`

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace Namespace.Filters {
    public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute {
        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {
            string issuer = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ida:Issuer");

            // default issuer, use if loading from AppSettings fails.
            if (issuer == null) {
                issuer = "https://login.windows.net/98297c67-25a1-404d-aab3-673b6096747f/wsfed";
            }
            var reply = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["reply"];
            reply = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(reply));
            var SignInRequest = string.Format(@"{0}?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=https%3a%2f%2f{myapp}%2f&wctx=rm%3d0%26id%3d2fcc67c4-3671-408b-b6fe-0c2cae2763c9%26ru%3d{1}&wct=2014-07-31T01%3a21%3a16Z", issuer, reply);
            filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(SignInRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

This attribute goes now in my `FilterConfig`

```
using Namespace.Filters;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Namespace {
    public class FilterConfig {
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters) {
            filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
            filters.Add(new CustomAuthorize());
        }
    }
}
```

And in my web.config I added this `passiveRedirectEnabled="false"` in `configuration/system.identityModel.services/federationConfiguration/wsFederation` that works perfect :)